# Language-agnostic way of displaying the generic types along with their type arguments?

Tags: .net, string, reflection, types, language-agnostic

Let's say I want to log/show this type's name:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<Guid, DateTime>>
```

What would be preferred:

1) Dictionary`2`string`Dictionary`2`Guid`DateTime

2) Dictionary`2(string, Dictionary`2(Guid, DateTime))

3) Dictionary< string , Dictionary < Guid, DateTime>>

How does JVM solve this?

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448918/486561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little long, but the `typeof(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<Guid, DateTime>>).FullName` is:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

The `typeof()` operator returns a `RuntimeType`, that is a .NET class. So the `FullName` is a property of a type of .NET, so it's official :-)

If you try to do a `Type.GetType(thatstring)`, you obtain the correct type :-)

A more compact version, without assembly shortnames, can be obtained with: `typeof(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<Guid, DateTime>>).ToString()`. This too can be used with `Type.GetType(...)`

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Guid,System.DateTime]]
```

Note that there is a limitation in `Type.GetType` with this format:

> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See AssemblyQualifiedName. **If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.**

If you are interested, here there is the full format:  [AssemblyQualifiedName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I never mentioned but I want a "friendly" name :). What do you think if I just strip the full qualifications: Dictionary\`2[String,Dictionary\`2[Guid,DateTime]]

Comment: @Den I think the namespaces are still important :-)

Comment: That's true, but when you do typeof(...).Name you don't get namespaces. I want the best of both worlds :). It's more for logging, rather than dynamic instantiation.

Comment: @Den Now, if you want to describe univocally a type, the namespace and assembly name are necessary. If you want to give a "general idea", then you can surely strip them. Perhaps using a Regex.

Comment: Thanks, by the way. A very quick, straightforward and thorough answer.

Comment: @Den The regex could be something like `new Regex(@"[^[,]*\.")` (it should strip all the namespaces) (you use it starting with the `Type.ToString()` version)